# GIT: fatal: Not a git repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm trying to add all my files from blog to git but I'm getting this error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository: myBlog/crayon-syntax-highlighter/js/jquery-colorpicker/../../.git/modules/js/jquery-colorpicker
```

I'm trying to add all the files like this:

```
git add --v -A
```

Any of you knows why or if there is any work around this?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Do you already have a git repository (i.e. have you cloned one or done a `git init`)?

Comment: @adrianbanks : Yes, I did the git init and I can add any file with the exception of that directory

Comment: It might be because of the `.git` directory further down your path. Do you have a `.git` directory inside your `crayon-syntax-highlighter` directory?

Comment: @adrianbanks that is a wordpress plugging I didn't add that .git in that directory

Answer (score 1):

Apparently:

- `myBlog/crayon-syntax-highlighter/` is a git repo (it has a `.git` in it)
- that git repo has declared a **[git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)** whose path should be `js/jquery-colorpicker`

If you don't have a `myBlog/crayon-syntax-highlighter/.gitmodules` file, then you can simply remove that declaration (`rm -Rf .git/modules`) in order to add all files then.

If you did not add a `.git` in that folder, but simply whish to add its files (without keeping its files history), then delete the `.git` entirely: you will then be able to `git add -A` everything.